# Is there an alternative to php imap extension

Tags: php, imap

My godaddy shared hosing service will not enable the IMAP extension for PHP. So I am in a pickle:

Is there a PHP function to replace the IMAP feature in PHP ?

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_last_error()
```

Here is the sample code that I am having problems with:

```
$mbox = imap_open ('{'.$email_host.':'.$email_port.'/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX', $email_username, $email_password) or die(imap_last_error());



        if(!$mbox){
            // send email letting them know bounce checking failed?
            // meh. later.
            echo 'Failed to connect when checking bounces.';
        }else{
            $MC = imap_check($mbox);
            $result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
            foreach ($result as $overview) {
                $this_subject = (string)$overview->subject;
                //echo "#{$overview->msgno} ({$overview->date}) - From: {$overview->from} <br> {$this_subject} <br>\n";
                $tmp_file = tempnam('/tmp/','newsletter_bounce');
                // TODO - tmp files for windows hosting.
                imap_savebody  ($mbox, $tmp_file, $overview->msgno);
                $body = file_get_contents($tmp_file);
                if(preg_match('/Message-ID:\s*<?Newsletter-(\d+)-(\d+)-([A-Fa-f0-9]{32})/imsU',$body,$matches)){
                    // we have a newsletter message id, check the hash and mark a bounce.
                    //"message_id" => "Newsletter-$send_id-$member_id-".md5("bounce check for $member_id in send $send_id"),
                    $send_id = (int)$matches[1];
                    $member_id = (int)$matches[2];
                    $provided_hash = trim($matches[3]);
                    $real_hash = md5("bounce check for $member_id in send $send_id");
                    if($provided_hash == $real_hash){
                        $sql = "UPDATE "._DB_PREFIX."newsletter_member SET `status` = 4, bounce_time = '".time()."' WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."' AND send_id = '".$send_id."' AND `status` = 3 LIMIT 1";
                        query($sql);
                        imap_delete($mbox, $overview->msgno);
                    }else{
                        // bad hash, report.
                    }
                }
                unlink($tmp_file);
            }
            imap_expunge($mbox);
            imap_close($mbox);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: IMAP has been a builtin for so long that no one seems to have written an external class for it. Honestly though, it's kinda of a dick move to disallow `imap_*` functions, and it makes me doubt if they allow `fsockopen()` at all. You should probably change hosts. On top of this issue, I've yet to hear anything *good* about GoDaddy's hosting.

Answer (score 4):

There's no PECL replacement for imap extension. If you dare, you can write one in PHP but that would be quite ineffective though. Alternative approach would be (assuming they are immune to customer's requests) to turn "GoDaddy" into "GoAwayDaddy" and change ISP to one who do not block this, quite elementary extension.

Answer (score 3):

This one works on godaddy shared hosting:
       http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4014-PHP-Retrieve-and-delete-messages-from-a-POP3-mailbox.html

And this one works too: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
include $class_name . '.php';
}
 include_once 'Zend/Mail/Storage/AbstractStorage.php';
include_once 'Zend/Mail/Storage/Pop3.php';
$mail = new Zend\Mail\Storage\Pop3(array('host'     => '$host',
                                     'user'     => '$user',
                                     'password' => '$password'));

echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
foreach ($mail as $message) {
   echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n</br>";
   echo $message->getContent() . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: does the actually imap function with zend work? ie  Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap with godaddy? I have scoured the internet and even contacted godaddy and they have no clue. I would love to hear your reply!

Comment: yes it does. you might have to add an autoload function to get the classes loaded.

Comment: Ahh I thank you I actually just got this running for Godaddy was telling me it wouldn't work! This does work with godaddy shared hosting! thanks for your help!

Comment: @tman, have you thought about accepting this answer if it helped you?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid I did not ask the question :)